# React js web application with Laravel passport Oauth2

Tags: reactjs, laravel, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have a backend admin panel created in Laravel 8, and i have installed passport security also. Admin frontend is working on vuejs by using laravel frontend scaffolding.
I have another one website in react js and one mobile application in React Native. The api to the web and mobile application is from laravel admin application. So what my doubt is, when i use external react js application what are the grand types should i use for authorization. And how will i segregate api routes for login user data and common data to the external react application.

Anyone can help me to get into the track.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to provide a way for others to use login from your site to log into other sites, or are you just trying to do auth on your own app?

Comment: Your question is hard to read. Separating routes is done by assigning the correct auth middleware, like `guest`, `web` or `auth:api`. Your external app should use one of the Oauth grant types. Since your app is a first party tool, you could go for a `PasswordClient`, on the other hand, it might be better and more save to go for a PKCE client, since you don't need to store the secret: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#code-grant-pkce

Comment: Am trying to do auth from from react website to laravel. All the api are coming from laravel only. So is it better i use 'Password Grant Client' for accessing apis after login and  'client_credentials' grand type for non authenticated apis ?